# Add a row to a sql data frame by pyspark

Tags: pyspark

As a newbie in spark, I can not find a function to insert a row in a sql dataframe by pyspark in this problem. For example, I have a dataframe like the following structure:

```
+----------+-----+
|      Time|Value|
+----------+-----+
|1364763600|115.0|
|1364763601|119.0|
|1364763603|116.5|
+----------+-----+
```

Now, I want to insert a row in the data frame between the second and the third row, the index is `1364763602`, following the second row's index, and the value should be the same as the second row, `119` in this case, the final data frame should be like:

```
+----------+-----+
|      Time|Value|
+----------+-----+
|1364763600|115.0|
|1364763601|119.0|
|1364763602|119.0|
|1364763603|116.5|
+----------+-----+
```

are there any effective methods to achieve this, the real dataframe is stored in different nodes.

Answer (score 4):

DataFrame is immutable distributed data structure, so you can't insert data. Even more, there is no  ordering defined on dataframe, so you can't insert record before or after the record. More than that, you don't even now, if 2 records are on the same node in cluster (unless you specify partitioner and test your records calling getPartition on it). All you can do is to create one-record DataFrame and union it with the old one `df1.union(df2)`

Comment: Thanks, @Vitaliy Kotlyarenko, I will try to modify the data before convert them into dataframe.